# Postman GET request to Binance API

Tags: post, get, request, postman, binance

I'm trying to send a `GET` request to Binance's API, but I don't exactly know how to.
Here is the documentation page: https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#account-information-user_data

I have a private `apiKey` and `secretKey`.
I can do a general request to Binance, but I cannot get my private data, using my private keys.

First try:
For the GET request in Postman I use this string:
https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account?timestamp=1499827319559&signature=`here_I_put_my_secret_key`

And I pass as a `header` as Danny suggested the `apiKey`.

But I get:

```
    {
    "code": -1021,
    "msg": "Timestamp for this request is outside of the recvWindow."
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Well, there's about 28 mentions of `recvWindow` in the docs so that's a good place to start. "It is recommended to use a small recvWindow of 5000 or less! The max cannot go beyond 60,000!"

Comment: I think just reading the documentation will help you here - https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#timing-security

Comment: Thanks for your response, I already try to set recvWindow=3000 or 50000 but it still generates the error..

Comment: I also tried to change timestamp value but nothing is changing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this correcting the time using `javascript` in Postman.
Another easy fix is to use the `ccxt` library : https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're after, as per the documentation.

https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#endpoint-security-type

> API-keys are passed into the Rest API via the `X-MBX-APIKEY` header.

In your Request, add that as the header key and your API Key as the value.

Comment: Thank for your reply. I'm now updating my question with my progress. I'm a beginner using API...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. This is working for me. Just Replace your API_KEY and SECRET

You need to retrieve serverTime time from **https://api.binance.com/api/v3/time** and need to use that serverTime to sign the request.

```
GET : https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account?timestamp={{timestamp}}&signature={{signature}}
```

Header:

```
Content-Type:application/json
X-MBX-APIKEY:YOUR_API_KEY
```

Pre-request Script :

```
pm.sendRequest('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/time', function (err, res) {
        console.log('Timestamp Response: '+res.json().serverTime);
        pm.expect(err).to.not.be.ok;
        var timestamp = res.json().serverTime;

        postman.setEnvironmentVariable('timestamp',timestamp)  
        postman.setGlobalVariable('timestamp',timestamp) 

        let paramsObject = {};

        const binance_api_secret = 'YOUR_API_SECRET';

        const parameters = pm.request.url.query;

        parameters.map((param) => {
            if (param.key != 'signature' && 
                param.key != 'timestamp' && 
                !is_empty(param.value) &&
                !is_disabled(param.disabled)) {
                    paramsObject[param.key] = param.value;
            }
        })
        
        Object.assign(paramsObject, {'timestamp': timestamp});

        if (binance_api_secret) {
            const queryString = Object.keys(paramsObject).map((key) => {
                return `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${paramsObject[key]}`;
            }).join('&');
            console.log(queryString);
            const signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(queryString, binance_api_secret).toString();
            pm.environment.set("signature", signature);
        }

        function is_disabled(str) {
            return str == true;
        }

        function is_empty(str) {
            if (typeof str == 'undefined' ||
                !str || 
                str.length === 0 || 
                str === "" ||
                !/[^\s]/.test(str) ||
                /^\s*$/.test(str) ||
                str.replace(/\s/g,"") === "")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the official Postman collections for the Binance API from here:

https://github.com/binance/binance-api-postman

Import the desired collection and environment in Postman, for instance
**binance_spot_api_v1.postman_collection.json**
and **binance_com_spot_api.postman_environment.json**

Add your API key to the **binance-api-key** environment variable and your secret key to the **binance-api-secret** variable.

**CAUTION:** Limit what the key can do in Binance key management. Do not use this key for production, only for testing. Create new key for production.

For the signed requests calculate the signature in a Pre-request Script then set the **signature** environment variable.

Example Pre-request Script:

```
function resolveQueryString() {
  const query = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(pm.request.url.query)) 
  const keyPairs = []
  for (param of query) {
    if (param.key === 'signature') continue
    if (param.disabled) continue
    if (param.value === null) continue
    const value = param.value.includes('{{') ? pm.environment.get(param.key) : param.value
    keyPairs.push(`${param.key}=${value}`)
  }
  return keyPairs.join('&')
}

const signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(
  resolveQueryString(),
  pm.environment.get('binance-api-secret')
).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)
pm.environment.set('signature', signature)
```